# Writing a Formula To Add Fifteen Minutes Until a Certain Time is Reached, Then Printing Blank After That Time is Reached?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now, the process I am using goes like this: Start Time: (C2)  End Time:  (C3)  (Both of which will be filled in by the user).
Then, I want the times to auto populate in fifteen minute increments in the cells below.

The formula I have is: =IF(OR(A5=$C$3,A5=" ")," ",A5+TIME(0,15,0)) where A5 is linked to the start time, and C3 is the end time.

The formula should be printing blank once the end time is reached; instead, if I enter a value >-4 PM as the end time, it continues printing in fifteen minute increments.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Dont you want to check (A5+Time(0,15,0))>$C$3?  This would allow the final time to print if the 15 minute multiple ends on the end time, and also works if the end time is not equal to a fifteen minute interval from the start time.  IE start time 1400, and end time 1505 would never trigger a blank on your check if I understand correctly.  Also take note of Ron Rosenfelds answer about rounding issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is a rounding issue having to do with the IEEE standard used to store numbers (lots of info on the web about this).

Try:

```
=IF(OR(ABS(N(A5)-$C$3)<0.0007,A5=" ")," ", A5+TIME(0,15,0))
```

The `N` function is used to convert the string you are storing `" "` into a zero, else you would be getting `#VALUE!` errors after the first blank.

As pointed out by @ForwardEd, if you cannot guarantee that the difference between the times entered will be a multiple of 15 minutes, you may want to change that check to a different value

For example:

```
=IF(OR(ABS(N(A5)-$C$3)<TIME(0,14,0),A5=" ")," ", A5+TIME(0,15,0))
```

Comment: I never tested, but does your modification take care of the case where A5+15 minutes is greater than the end time as well?  That seemed to be a missing case if the difference between start and end time was not a multiple of 15 minutes.  IE start time 1400, end time 1505.

Comment: @ForwardEd No, it solves the problem posited by the OP, where he used an equality for the test. But, especially since the times will be user entered, your point is a good one, and I'll add that.